# CouchDB econnrefused

Tags: couchdb

I am having trouble adding an external process to my CouchDB database. Currently the database contains a few records, all of which have standalone attachments in the form of PNG or JPG. I want to add the Couch_Image_Resizer (by KlausTrainer) to the database so that I can use the queries offered by the Image Resizer to dynamically resize the images on request. However currently it only returns an error when the URL command is used:

```
http://virtualMachineAddress/_image/archive/test/the_starry_night_painting.jpg?resize=500x500

{"error":"error","reason":"{conn_failed,{error,econnrefused}}"}
```

I have followed the instructions to the letter, replacing any instance of localhost or 127.0.0.1 with the IP address of my virtual machine (which has been made elastic so should never change) where needed.

I have also altered the local.ini file as was instructed so that it includes the following:

```
[httpd_global_handlers]
_image = {couch_httpd_proxy, handle_proxy_req, <<"http://127.0.0.1:5985">>}
```

Finally I have ensured that the program is running via the ./start.sh command. If this is run more than once it returns the following, I am usure as to if it is relevant:

```
root@couchdb couchdb/couch_image_resizer# ./start.sh
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) {application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) {application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})`
```

**Some info that might be helpful**

erl_crash.dump: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HR6UtGFF)

Server is a virtual AWS machine running Debian 7.9 Wheezy.
The database is hosted externally on this server.

CouchDB version: 1.2.0

The database is not in Admin Party mode, accounts with permissions are in use.

GitHub link: [Couch_Image_Resizer](https://github.com/KlausTrainer/couch_image_resizer)

Erlang: erts-5.9.1 64-bit

ImageMagick: 6.8.9-9

I am clearly missing something here, if you need anything else just ask. If anyone can shed any light on what I am missing I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this although there may be others.

Stop the service, set its permissions to be owned exclusively by the couchdb user and then adding the start.sh file path to the [osdaemon] section of CouchDB's local.ini before restarting the database and also launching the application as a root user. Doing this was able to kick-start the service and it now functions normally and as intended.